# Free function not working

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have the following C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        int *test = malloc(sizeof(*test));
        test = 500;
        free(test);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The free function does not seem to work as the allocated memory grows to 2GB within a few seconds. What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only `free` a pointer that is a return of `malloc`.

In writing `test = 500`, you've changed the memory location pointed to by `test`. Trying to free that is *undefined behaviour*.

To assign a value to your allocated integer, *derefence* it: `*test = 500`;

Answer (score 5):

```
test = 500;
```

This changed the memory address. Therefor the original memory you allocated was never freed.

Maybe you meant to write:

```
*test = 500;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the *test* pointer, not the value pointed to by *test*.  The code should be corrected as follows:

```
*test = 500;
```

instead of

```
test = 500;
```